# SQL Server Connection Problems

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2000

I have one server out of three which cannot connect to our sql server 2000 using the FQDN but can connect using the non FQDN.   None of the other servers are having this problem.

This problem occurs under ADO connections to a SQL Server 2000 database.

The database has encryption turned on.   I don't want to turn it off.

Does anyone have any ideas of what to look at?

Notes:
You can ping or telnet to the sql server using both FQDN and non FQDN.
The other two servers are working fine and all servers are on the same subnet.
All the servers are running Windows 2000.

Comment: Should be on serverfault.com.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What error do you get?

Probably the certificate used to encrypt the connection (the server SSL cert, possible self signed) has the simple, non-qualified, name of the machine as subject. The client thus rejects the cert when it attempts to connect, breaking the connection.

Comment: Microsoft OLE DB Provider for SQL
Server: [DBNETLIB][ConnectionRead (recv()).]General network error. Check your network documentation.

Comment: See what certificate is that server using. http://support.microsoft.com/kb/316898/ has step-by-step procedures on how to find the used certificate (in the Troubleshooting section), as well on how to replace it.

Comment: The certificate is valid.  If there is a certificate on the client side, can that affect the connection, or does only the certificate on the server side affect it?

Comment: Is valid, but who is it issued to? The **Issued To** in the certificate viewer is for the FQDN or for the simple machine name? How is this compared with the other machines where FQDN works?

Comment: Interesting it is registered to our domain as such.  *.mine.com.
All the machines are something.mine.com.   All the other machines work fine and they are something1.mine.com etc.

Comment: Do all clients have this problem, or only one? Ie. can other clients connect to fqdn on this server?